# Scheduling messages in MassTransit when using the encrypted serializer

Tags: scheduling, masstransit

I'm trying to send both scheduled and recurring messages using MassTransit, but we currently use the encrypted serializer across all of our projects.  As a result, all messages get serialized into BSON format, but it appears MassTransit only supports scheduling messages that are JSON or XML format.  Taken directly from their source:

```
        if (string.Compare(context.ContentType, "application/vnd.masstransit+json",
            StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
            == 0)
            body = TranslateJsonBody(body, context.Message.Destination.ToString());
        else if (string.Compare(context.ContentType, "application/vnd.masstransit+xml",
            StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
            body = TranslateXmlBody(body, context.Message.Destination.ToString());
        else
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Only JSON and XML messages can be scheduled");
```

Is there any sort of workaround that would allow for the scheduling of encrypted messages?  Or is there an easy way to selectively exclude message types from being encrypted?